# Proper way to manipulate the depth buffer for InstancedBufferGeometry using RawShaderMaterial WITH TRANSPARENCY in three.js?

Tags: typescript, three.js, glsl, transparency, depth-buffer

I just cant seem to wrap my head around why transparency works from one side of a semi transparent instance and not the other when the depth buffer seems to be correct.

I am trying to set up a (semi) wireframe grid of cells (with quad like edges rather than tri edges) that are regular in the x and y directions but can vary in depth (the z direction). I would like to be able to render up to around 2 million cells (that's 24 million triangles if my math is correct), and since every cell is a variation on a rectangular prism, I used Three.js's InstancedBufferGeometry so that I can let the shader do the heavy lifting with translation, scale, color, etc. The barycentric function does great with the wireframe. I would like for the cells to be semi-transparent (more opaque wires, less opaque faces. They seem correct when viewed from one side but are opaque when viewed from the other.

Vertex Shader:

```c
  precision lowp float;
  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
  uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
  attribute vec3 position;
  attribute vec3 translation;
  attribute vec3 scale;
  attribute vec3 color;
  attribute float near;
  attribute float far;
  attribute vec3 center;
  attribute float colorByDepth;
  vec3 transform(inout vec3 position, vec3 T, vec3 S) {
    position *= S;
    position += T;
    return position;
  }
  varying float vDepth;
  varying vec3 vColor;
  varying vec3 vCenter;
  varying float vColorByDepth;
  void main() {
    vec3 pos = position;
    transform(pos, translation, scale);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( pos, 1.0 );
    float z = distance(vec4(cameraPosition, 1.0), gl_Position);
    vDepth = (z - near) / (far - near);
    vColor = color;
    vCenter = center;
    vColorByDepth = colorByDepth;
  }
```

Fragment Shader:

```c
  #extension GL_EXT_frag_depth : enable
  precision lowp float;
  varying float vDepth;
  varying vec3 vColor;
  varying vec3 vCenter;
  varying float vColorByDepth;
  float edgeFactorTri() {
    vec3 d = fwidth(vCenter.xyz);
    vec3 a3 = smoothstep(vec3(0.0), d * 1.5, vCenter.xyz);
    return min(min(a3.x, a3.y), a3.z);
  }
  void main() {
    vec4 edgeColor = vec4(vColor, 0.1);
    vec4 faceColor = vec4(vColor, 0.01);
    float edgeFactor = edgeFactorTri();
    vec4 opaqueWhite = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    vec4 opaqueBlack = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    float depthFactor = vDepth;
    gl_FragColor = vColorByDepth > 0.5 ? mix(opaqueWhite, opaqueBlack, depthFactor) : mix(edgeColor, faceColor, edgeFactor);
    gl_FragDepthEXT = depthFactor;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hexwrench/ob04a3xp/138/

For this fiddle, I have included a small example data set. The cells are colored by cell top depth. When the mouse is down on the rotating grid, the cells are colored by depth from the camera. Notice that when the mesh is viewed from an angle where it is "c" shaped, proper transparency is observed. When the mesh is viewed from the other side and the mesh is "ɔ" shaped (thanks google), the cells are (incorrectly) opaque.

Comment: `material.depthTest = false;` or `material.depthWrite = false;` are options for you.

Comment: @WestLangley ...but I need depth testing / depth writing for the cells to not show up out of order... unless I am missing something major here? Here is the fiddle with depth test and depth write set to false on the material: 

https://jsfiddle.net/hexwrench/ob04a3xp/142/

Comment: @Hexwrench You should look into [order-independent transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency). There are a few WebGL implementations.